# Python while loop for API offsets

Tags: python, loops

I did my best writing this API, but I'm now stuck on the while loop.

**My main goal is to scan batch by batch the API results and write it in the database.**

The way the code is written is bringing me straight the results as offset=4000

Don't know what am I doing wrong.

Follow my code

```
    #!/bin/env python

from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
from re import X
from typing import ItemsView
import requests
import json
import hashlib
import base64
import time
import hmac
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import pyodbc

#Account Info
AccessId = ''
AccessKey = ''
Company = ''

#Request Info
httpVerb ='GET'
resourcePath = '/alert/alerts'

offset = 0
while offset < 5000:


# Query parameters
    queryParams ='?size=1000&offset=' + str(offset) + '&sort=-startEpoch&filter=cleared:*,rule:critical'

    offset += 1000 

data = ''

#Construct URL 
url = 'https://'+ Company +'.logicmonitor.com/santaba/rest' + resourcePath + queryParams

print(url)

#Get current time in milliseconds
epoch = str(int(time.time() * 1000))

#Concatenate Request details
requestVars = httpVerb + epoch + data + resourcePath

#Construct signature
hmac1 = hmac.new(AccessKey.encode(),msg=requestVars.encode(),digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac1.encode())

#Construct headers
auth = 'LMv1 ' + AccessId + ':' + signature.decode() + ':' + epoch
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization':auth}

#Make request
response = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=headers)

data = response.json()

alerts_df = pd.DataFrame(data['data']['items'])
alerts_df = alerts_df[['id','internalId','rule','monitorObjectName','startEpoch','endEpoch','cleared','resourceTemplateName']]
alerts_df['startEpoch'] = pd.to_datetime(alerts_df['startEpoch'],unit='s')
alerts_df['endEpoch'] = alerts_df['endEpoch'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,unit='s') if x !=0 else x)


print(alerts_df)
```

Comment: Not making the request until after the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the variable constantly before even making one request.
Also, the while loop should be <= 5000 if you want to include the 5000 in the loop.

There are two ways to achieve it.

1. append the results to a list for later use
2. make the request after you generated the string

Comment: Hey, @Raavgo thanks for your feedback. I will do some research on how to append the results .
Would you mind helping me indicate wherein the code is the best place to put the loop?